# Unable to change registry on Windows 10

Tags: windows, vb.net, registry

I'm trying to change the value of the Shell registry key on Windows 10 using the following code:

```
Public Function overwriteStartup()
    Try
        Dim winlogon As RegistryKey = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", True)
        winlogon.SetValue("AutoRestartShell", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
        winlogon.SetValue("Shell", Application.ExecutablePath, RegistryValueKind.String)
        winlogon.Flush()
        winlogon.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

The issue is that Shell and AutoRestartShell are not changing.
If I add `MessageBox.Show(My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon").GetValue("Shell"))` between `winlogon.Close()` and `Return True`, I get a message box that shows the correct value (which means that the value was changed), but when I check regedit, it shows the original value, so it did not actually change the value.
[image: Diffinent values, should be the same]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the target framework to .NET 4 and set target CPU to AnyCPU, it works now.

Comment: The state of the "prefer 32-bit" flag might be important too.  Windows shows a different part of the registry to 32-bit apps (the material under Wow6432Node).

Answer (score 0):

If your app can **read** the registry value - You must need to provide administrative privileges before letting your app write registry values. Go to the app manifest and set the privilege to `requireAdministrator` then try again, it should work.

If you remove the exception handling Try Catch, then you'll get to know the exact reason.

Comment: I already have requested execution level set to highest available. Removing Try Catch doesn't change anything, no exception is thrown

Comment: Refresh the registry page by pressing F5, that doesn't automatically updates. That may work. The reason is, if the value prints to be changed, then the value must be changed.